# Rails 7: Connect to different databases conditionally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, sharding

I have a Rails 7 application and i am trying to connect to different databases conditionally.

Below is my `database.yml`

```
development:
  primary:
    adapter: postgresql
    database: development
    host: localhost
    user: postgres
    password: root
  main_red:
    adapter: postgresql
    username: etl
    database: "<%= ENV['API_MAIN_DATABASE_NAME'] %>"
    password: "<%= ENV['API_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>"
    host: "<%= ENV['API_DATABASE_HOST'] %>"
    database_tasks: false
  main_blue:
    adapter: postgresql
    username: etl
    database: "<%= ENV['API_MAIN_DATABASE_NAME'] %>"
    password: "<%= ENV['API_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>"
    host: "<%= ENV['API_DATABASE_HOST'] %>"
    database_tasks: false
  main_green:
    adapter: postgresql
    username: etl
    database: "<%= ENV['API_MAIN_DATABASE_NAME'] %>"
    password: "<%= ENV['API_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>"
    host: "<%= ENV['API_DATABASE_HOST'] %>"
    database_tasks: false
```

below is a model definition

```
class ExternalRecord < ApplicationRecord
  self.abstract_class = true
  #establish_connection :main
  connects_to database: {main_red: :main_red, main_green: :main_green, main_blue: :main_blue}
end
```

I want to perform a read from either `main_red, main_green or main_blue` and perform a insert in the `primary` database.

below is my code

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connected_to(role: :main_red) do
            result = Api::V2::BulkExport.where(Tier: @tier, Version: 'v2').order(order).ransack(@params[:q]).result.limit(@limit)
          end
track_usage(user_id: @user.id, end_point: request.path, rows_returned: result.count)
```

The reading from the database is working as expected but looks like i am not able to connect back to the primary database. I see the following error

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished (No connection pool for 'ExternalRecord' found.):
```

Any help on this would be great, Thanks.

Comment: Maybe it's because you didn't define a `primary` role? IIRC, you can connect to a database directly without setting up roles via `ActiveRecord::Base.connected_to(database: :main_red)`.